# Adobe AIR make screenshot

Tags: apache-flex, air, screenshot

I have an adobe air application and it must make screenshot for entire screen (not only app area) and save it to a file on hdd.

Could you give me a link how can I achieve this?

thank you

Answer (score 4):

On Windows, you can use this one to grab screenshot ...
https://github.com/pcichon/ScreenShooter
it uses Native Extensions for AIR.

Answer (score 3):

Video Tutorial:

http://gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=125

http://gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=126

Answer (score 1):

Look at this [project](http://www.flexjunk.com/2011/02/24/desktop-screen-capture-in-adobe-air/); which is called the [Nitro ScreenCap component](https://store.nitromation.com/nitro-store/store/main.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can build native extension for all platforms.
If are making windows application you can make dll with c or c++.
Here are some usefull links for start.

http://easynativeextensions.com/air-native-extension-for-windows/
https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2307093